# How can i solve the value too large for dtype('float32') error? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, dtype

I have a dataset that contains numbers. But when I try to fit with this command:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get this error :

> Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').

But there are no null cells in my dataset.
 Not scaled data_X

```
[[0 0 4 ... 0 -21.4 6]
 [1 0 2 ... 0 0.0 0]
 [0 0 2 ... 0 805.9 7]
 ...
 [1 0 2 ... 1 -20.2 0]
 [1 0 3 ... 1 1031.0 5]
 [0 1 3 ... 1 0.0 0]]
```

**scaled X_train is like this:**

```
 [[ 0.64649731 -0.63390308  0.74842646  0.41698984 -0.65263096]
 [-1.54679684 -0.63390308 -0.6061627   0.41698984 -0.65263096]
 [ 0.64649731  1.57752823  0.07113188  0.41698984  0.7140774 ]
 ...
 [ 0.64649731 -0.63390308 -0.6061627   0.41698984 -0.65263096]
 [-1.54679684 -0.63390308  0.07113188  0.41698984  0.7140774 ]
 [ 0.64649731 -0.63390308  0.74842646  0.41698984 -0.65263096]]
```

When I drop float numbers from this dataset, the problem solved.
But this is not the solution.
What can I do to avoid this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your largest and smallest value? is it too large/small for `float32`???

Comment: The error already suggest what to do: **imputation**, i.e. you need to replace `NaN` with some other values.

Comment: there is not none numbers , i fixed @QuangHoang

Comment: `None` and `NaN` are two different things.

Comment: Sure i fixed self.data[self.data==np.inf]=np.nan
            self.data.fillna(0, inplace=True)

Comment: "When I drop float numbers from this dataset, the problem solved" t looks like all numbers there are floats, did you drop the entire dataset?

Comment: Nope, this data set is scaled. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change value for float 32:

```
X_train= np.float32(X_train)
```

And/or replace Nan and inf:

```
X_train=np.nan_to_num(X_train, nan=-9999, posinf=33333333, neginf=33333333)
```